What is correct cipher name for the cryptsetup to use HCTR2 wideblock encryption?
By googling, trial and error I came up with the following string:
cryptsetup benchmark -c aes-xctr-plain64

but I'm not sure whether it is correct.
The cipher spec aes-xctr-plain64,polyval-generic fits also and gives the same speed results. Probably they mean exactly the same?

The right one is cryptsetup benchmark -c aes-hctr2-plain64.
You'll need cryptsetup 2.7.3 [0] at least for the benchmark command to work. The luksFormat and open commands do work with much earlier versions (at least 2.6.1) though as you could see by the time I wrote my blogpost on [1].
[0] https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/main/docs/v2.7.3-ReleaseNotes?ref_type=heads
[1] https://klondike.es/klog/2023/07/30/using-hctr2-with-luks/
